# AWT event thread interruption

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt

I have code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test2 {

JFrame frame = null;
JPanel panel = null;
JButton button = null;
Task task = null;
Indicator indicator = null;
Runnable computation;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test2().start();
}

public void start() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Dialog());
}

private void process1() {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        result = (int) Math.ceil(++result + Math.sqrt(result));

        System.out.println("proc1 " + result);
    }
}

private void process2() {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        result = (int) Math.ceil(++result + Math.sqrt(result)*500);

        System.out.println("proc2 " + result);
    }
}

private class Computation implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        process1();
        task.setProgress(2);
        process2();
        task.setProgress(3);
    }

}

private class Dialog implements Runnable {

    public Dialog() {
    }

    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        button = new JButton("b1");
        panel.add(button);
        indicator = new Indicator();
        task = new Task();
        task.addObserver(indicator);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        computation = new Computation();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(computation);
    }
}

private class Task extends Observable {

    int progress;

    public Task() {

    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }
}

private class Indicator implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        button.setText(((Task)arg0).getProgress()+"");
    }
}
}
```

So I have two time-consuming operations (process1 and process2). My aim is after process1 is complete, update swing-button (see task.setProgress method).

Problem consists in that update is performed after process1() and process2() are completed.

Answer (score 4):

> ..update is performed after process1() and process2() are completed.

Don't perform long running tasks on the EDT, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details.  One way to achieve that is to use a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

---

> ..if I use two `SwingWorkers` for performing `process1()` and `process2()`, then order of their execution is unpredictable. I need `process2()` follows by `process1()`. How I can obtain this?

Call both methods in the [`doInBackground()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground%28%29) method of 1 `SwingWorker`, calling [SwingWorker.setProgress(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29) with the appropriate values at the appropriate times.  E.G.

```
... doInBackground() {
    setProgress(0);
    process1();
    setProgress(50);
    process2();
    setProgress(100);
}
```

Comment: +1 @CHEM_Eugene and I think that `button.setText(((Task)arg0).getProgress()+"");` is called only once, then there any updates for progress, but you can debug that, add there System.out.println, or wrap this code line to the invokeLater()

Comment: Andrew Thompson, if I use two SwingWorkers for performing process1() and process2(), then order of their execution is unpredictable. I need process2() follows by process1(). How I can obtain this?

Comment: Use one `SwingWorker` that calls both `process1()` then `process2()` (in that order).  Though I must have misunderstood you, since that answer seems intuitively obvious.

Comment: I can't use one SwingWorker because of I need update progress bar after process1() and after process2()

Comment: Sorry, I gave wrong example... Really, process1() and process2() work with GUI. So, I can't invoke their with SwingWorker.

Comment: @CHEM_Eugene you have to implements SwingWorker if process1() and process2() work with GUI, sure that's possible with Runnable#Thread, sure similair methods you used in your code but little bit wrong to implements all methods in you code, split your question to the 1) GUI, 2) BackGround Task, 2a) BackGround Task by using Runnable + GUI, 2b) BackGround Task by using SwingWorker, 2a) BackGround Task and Concurency in Swing, 3) Observable and invokeAndWait()

Comment: @Andrew Thompson not sure what you mean, but maybe, I think that SwingWorker#publish() is there for stepped output to the GUI too

Comment: @mKorbel  re. `publish()` that sounds right, I was just roughing out some general lines of code (unless I post an SSCCE, presume I have not tested it).